# Codeigniter routing permalinks

Tags: php, codeigniter

Alright so I am using index.php which is located inside my views folder as my main view. I load all other views inside it (as you can see from the code bellow).

Now when I make a route like about/(:any) it wont load any of my CSS or such..

Routes

```
$route['about']                     =  'about'; // works fine
$route['about/(:any)']              =  'about/get_specific_about/$1'; //problematic one
```

Now this is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/partials/header.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/partials/footer.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/<?php echo $meta['css']; ?>.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php $this->load->view("partials/header");         ?>
        <?php $this->load->view($meta['page']);             ?>
        <?php $this->load->view("partials/footer");         ?>

    </body>


</html>
```

Now whenever I use the route with (:any), the code will load the view but it wont be able to find for example footer.css or header.css.. If I used for example ../public/css/header.css then it will...

Code for the About controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class About extends CI_Controller {

    private $data = [
        'meta'  => [
            'page'          =>  "pages/about",
            'css'           =>  "about",
            'description'   =>  "test"
        ],

    ];

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->helper('html');

        $this->load->view('index', $this->data);
    }

    public function get_specific_about($user) {
        $tmp_data                           =   [];
        $tmp_data['meta']['css']            =   "profiles/".$user;
        $tmp_data['meta']['page']           =   "profiles/".$user;
        $tmp_data['meta']['description']    =   "test";
        $tmp_data['meta']['extended']       =   true;

        $this->load->view('index', $tmp_data);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the routes that are the problem; it's that you are using relative paths to your assets. Try anchoring asset paths to the root by prefixing them with `$this->config->site_url()`

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute URL links for href

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="<?php echo base_url('public/css/partials/header.css'); ?>>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="<?php echo base_url('public/css/partials/footer.css'); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="<?php echo base_url("public/css/{$meta['css']}.css"); ?>" />
</head>
```

If you're not using `.htaccess' to rewrite URLs without`index.php`then substitute`site_url`for`base_url`.